# SSIS Name based mapping for flat file import

Tags: ssis, etl

A vendor of ours cannot guarantee the flat files column order. How does the Flat File Connection handle when the columns are rearranged?

Answer (score 0):

The Flat File Connection will not rearrange the columns if they appear in a different order. You will have to load the data with headers and reorder them dynamically, either using SSIS or a database.

Comment: how do i load them with headers? do i uncheck "column names in the first data row" and use script task to find the first row and remap in code?

Comment: Yes, you need to uncheck "column names in the first data row" and make sure you start the import at row 0. You could use a script task to reorder the rows and output the data to a intermediate file. Alternatively you could use a combination of an unpivot and pivot to reorder the columns.